# php using wrong ini file, cant find curl function

Tags: php, curl

I am just having trouble with some php code after upgrading from `v5.3 to v7.0.29.` The error is now my my web site can't find the `curl_init` function.

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

if i go to dos and run `"php --ini"` it shows the system is pointing to an unrelated version of `php.ini` setup to `php 5.3`, something I guess IIS installed.

```
C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v7.1\php.ini
```

How do i actually make the system point to the new `php.ini` file set up as part of the upgrade to `7.0.29`, which i believe is the cause of the problem.

Both `php.ini` files have the **"extension=php_curl.dll"**

I don't know what I should be doing, or why this IIS `php.ini` was referenced in the first place.

I have tried changing the path, but this doesn't seem to have an effect.

thanks

Comment: i did actually just end up using the php version iis installed but would love to know how to change the way a system locates the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

first off, use `<?php phpinfo(~0);` to find the actual php.ini file used by php, look for `Loaded Configuration File`, when that's done, if `extension=php_curl.dll` really is part of php.ini, then it's trying to load the curl extension, but failing somehow. because you're not getting any errors, it's safe to assume that you have `display_startup_errors` disabled. enable `display_startup_errors` in php.ini, and you should get an error explaining why the curl extension couldn't be loaded, fix that/those errors, and curl should be available. (my best guess, you don't have `extension=php_openssl.dll`, or it's too low, you must load the openssl extension BEFORE loading the curl extension, curl depends on it being loaded.)